# How to programmatically hide the left view controller in a split view controller in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm developing an app in Swift for iOS 10.  The UI for my app uses the inbox UISplitViewController.  When my app is running on an iPad in portrait orientation I'd like the left view controller popover to automatically hide once an item is selected.

The only answers I've been able to find use methods that no longer exist or are deprecated.

To be more specific, I'd like to hide the view on the left in the screenshot below once an item in the table has been selected.

[image: Screenshot of app with menu visible.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, ensure you have a reference to your `UISplitViewController` from the app delegate setup. E.g.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.primaryOverlay
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    splitViewController.delegate = self
}
```

Then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method for your table view, add something like:

```
    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .portrait {
        splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
    }
```

To animate:

```
    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .portrait {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I accepted this as the solution because it does what I asked.  However, it would be nice if the "primary" view could slide out of view instead of just disappearing.

Comment: statusBarOrientation is deprecated in iOS 13+ 

You can uses 

```if UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape == false {```

instead

Answer (score 1):

I struggled finding a solution for this but I managed to figure out and get the following working:

```
splitViewController?.hide(.primary)
```

Thats it!

Get the nearest split view controller then you can hide its primary, secondary and other bits within .hide.